# Bayesian decision rule for disease classification

Tags: statistics, bayesian, hypothesis-testing, bayes-theorem

I'm currently trying to solve the following exercise:
A disease occurs at 0.1 percent of the population. A test for detecting the disease classifies 97 percent of the ill people as ill but also 2 percent of the healthy people. Let $\ell_0 \geq 0$ describe the loss if a healthy person is rated as ill and otherwise let $\ell_1 \geq 0$ describe the loss if an ill person is classified as healthy. Now one should formalise the Bayesian decision problem and find an Bayes-optimal decision rule.

I tried the following:
Let $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F}, (P_\vartheta)_{\vartheta \in \theta})$ be the statistical model, $\theta = \{0,1\}$, $A = \{0,1\}$ and $\ell(\vartheta,a)=\ell_0 1(\vartheta=1, a=0)+\ell_11(\vartheta=0, a=1)$, $a \in A, \vartheta \in \theta$. Furthermore let $\rho: \mathcal{X} \to A$ be a test for $H_0: \vartheta = 0$ vs. $H_1: \vartheta = 1$ and set $\pi_0=\pi(\{0\})=0.999$, $\pi_1=1-\pi_0$.

Now I'm not sure how to continue. I think $\pi$ should be the prior and $P_0(\rho(X)=1)=0.02$ and $P_1(\rho(X)=1)=0.97$. Is this right? Could you provide a tip what I should try next? I don't really know how to calculate the risk and finally how to minimize the integral in $\rho.$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $Ti$ denotes the event that test shows ill. $Ai$ denotes a person is actually ill. $Th$ denotes that test shows healthy. $Ah$ shows a person is actually healthy.

What we know from the hypothesis is $P(Ai)=0.001$, $P(Ti|Ai)=0.97$ and $P(Ti|Ah)=0.02$. What we need is $P(Ah|Ti)$ corresponding to the loss $l_0$ and $P(Ai|Th)$ corresponding to $l_1$.

Use Bayes' rule, we can compute $P(Ah|Ti)$ and $P(Ai|Th)$ from what we already knew from hypothesis.

By Bayes' theorem, $P(Ah|Ti)=\frac{P(Ti|Ah)P(Ah)}{P(Ti)}$ where $P(Ti|Ah)=0.02$, $P(Ah)=1-P(Ai)$, $P(Ti)=P(Ti|Ah)+P(Ti|Ai)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it again now. One thing: I think you mean $P(Ai)=0.001$ since it is 0.1 percent, right?

Comment: I tried it but I don't know where to use the Bayes rule. I think $P(Th|Ai)=1-P(Ti|Ai)=0.03$ and $P(Ti|Ah)=0.02$ was already given. Where did I go wrong? Because this result I already had earlier this day and I don't know how to continue with this...

Comment: @Conny I have modified it. Hope it's clear now. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Thank you! I calculated the probability as $P(Ah|Ti)=\frac{0.01998}{0.02095}$. This is about 95 percent. Is this even possible? And how should I proceed? I really don't know how to find the decision rule.

Comment: Actually, $P(Ah|Ai)$ is $\frac{0.02\times 0.999}{0.99}$

Comment: For Bayesian decision rule, just follow the formula here. http://www.commsp.ee.ic.ac.uk/~vb198/compilation/node3.html

Comment: I think you mean $P(Ah|Ti)$ since $P(Ah|Ai)$ should obviously equal zero. How do you get $0.99$ as denominator? Shouldn't it be $P(Ti|Ah) \cdot P(Ah) + P(Ti|Ai) \cdot P(Ai) = 0.02095$? Furthermore I have a general question considering the Bayesian decision rule: What does it mean in this context? What does the decision rule describe?

Comment: Can I take a look at the context where this problem come from? I'm a little confused about what the problem is asking us to do.

Comment: It's an exercise from an exercise sheet of mathematical statistics. I can't really provide more context. We just learned the definition of decision rules and Bayes-optimal decision rules. That's the reason why I'm also confused about what we should do. I'll just write down my ideas and we will see what the corrector thinks about them.